# Can't change default language switch keys combination (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu

Can't change it on the latest Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. In Settings there's no reaction to any new combination - it's just stuck on a system default "Super+Space", though I tried "Ctrl+Shift", "Alt+Shift", "Win+Shift" - nothing, though Ctrl+R, for example - it works. :)
Tried in Tweaks as well by selecting different combinations but still didn't succeed, they just don't work - any of them.
Looks like this default setting for switching languages is concrete. :) Googled the issue but all links date back to good old 2013-2015 years with no solutions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community When you trying to select with mouse arrow different language it  not changing. HOT KEYS does work, did not tried to change them, but the beh.-r exists U22.04

Comment: @Community Update this beh-r exist if you set lang param to opened window selection. So i switched back to system wide and it works as expected.

Comment: @Andrei Check that GLOBAL SETTINGS > Keyboard parameter `Input Source Switching` is not set to use ind. windows.